# Evaluate : $\int \frac {e^{2x} -1}{e^x +1} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate : $$\int \dfrac {e^{2x} -1}{e^x +1} dx$$

My Attempt:
$$\int \dfrac {e^{2x}-1}{e^x+1}dx\\
=\int \left(\dfrac {e^{2x}}{e^x +1} - \dfrac {1}{e^x+1}\right)dx\\
=\int \dfrac {e^{2x}}{e^x+1} dx - \int \dfrac {dx}{e^x+1}$$

Comment: Try $e^{2x}-1=(e^x-1)(e^x+1)$..

Comment: It boils down to computing $\int \frac{t^2-1}{t(t+1)}\,dt = \int \frac{t-1}{t}\,dt$ which is not hard at all.

Answer (score 1):

I will continue from where you left
$$=\int \dfrac {e^{2x}}{e^x+1} dx - \int \dfrac {dx}{e^x+1}$$
Now $$\int \dfrac {e^{2x}}{e^x+1} dx$$
Apply $u-$substitution $u=e^x+1$ and we get
$$\int \dfrac {e^{2x}}{e^x+1} dx=\int\frac{u-1}{u}du=u-\ln|u|=e^x+1-\ln|e^x+1|$$
And 
$$ \int \dfrac {1}{e^x+1}dx=\int1-\dfrac {1}{e^x+1}dx=x-\ln|e^x+1|$$
$$\int \dfrac {e^{2x}}{e^x+1} dx - \int \dfrac {dx}{e^x+1}=e^x+1-\ln|e^x+1|-x+\ln|e^x+1|$$
$$=e^x-x+1+C$$
$$\int\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^x+1}=e^x-x+1+C$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{x}+1}\,dx
=\int\left(e^x-\frac{e^x+1}{e^x+1}\right)\,dx
=\int e^xdx-\int1 dx
=e^x-x+c, \quad c\in\mathbb R$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int \dfrac {e^{2x} -1}{e^x +1} dx = \int \dfrac {(e^{x} -1)(e^{x} + 1)}{e^x +1} dx=\int ({e^x -1}) dx=e^x - x +C  
$$